# How to get sequence.nextval from SQL in JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have 5 tables where I use the same sequence's next value. The problem is, the subsequent tables gets a bigger value than the previous ones.

My code is like this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table1(id, name) VALUES (id_seq.nextval, ?)"; 
ps.setString(1, "bar"); 
ps.executeUpdate();     
sql = "INSERT INTO table2(id, name) VALUES (id_seq.nextval, ?)";
ps.setString(1, "tar"); 
ps.executeUpdate();
sql = "INSERT INTO table3(id, name) VALUES (id_seq.nextval, ?)";
ps.setString(1, "par"); 
ps.executeUpdate();
sql = "INSERT INTO table4(id, name) VALUES (id_seq.nextval, ?)";
ps.setString(1, "car"); 
ps.executeUpdate();
sql = "INSERT INTO table5(id, name) VALUES (id_seq.nextval, ?)";
ps.setString(1, "rar"); 
ps.executeUpdate();
```

My sequence is like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "ID_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999 INCREMENT BY 1         START WITH 10 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

Now when I look at my tables, table1's ID is 10, but table2's ID is 11 and table3's ID is 12..... I want all the tables' IDs to be same. What should I do? 
Thank you in advance.

edit: Had to include more tables than 2 to have more general question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually I found the answer online. I need to do this:

```
String sql = "select ID_SEQ.nextval from DUAL";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if(rs.next())
    int nextID_from_seq = rs.getInt(1);
```

And when I insert this value to database, I type this:

```
String sql2 = "INSERT INTO table1(id, name) VALUES (?, ?)"; 
ps.setInt(1, nextID_from_seq); 
ps.setString(2, "tar");
ps.executeUpdate();     
sql2 = "INSERT INTO table2(id, name) VALUES (?, ?)";
ps.setInt(1, nextID_from_seq); 
ps.setString(2, "par");
ps.executeUpdate();
...
...
```

The first string sql is "select ID_SEQ.nextval from DUAL." That "DUAL" in the end is not table name or anything. It's just one of the given or provided functionality by oracle. I can get any sequence's nextval by using it.

Comment: I am confused, the question is tag as `mysql` but the answer accepted as correct is for `oracle` database

Answer (score 1):

You can use `id_seq.currval` for the second table. It will reuse the same id.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO table2(id, name) VALUES (id_seq.currval, ?)";
```

Comment: But what if I have a third table? or more than 3-4 tables? And I want to use the same ID for all those tables? There has to be another way? Thanks

Comment: Maybe an outdated question but you can reuse it insert all statement.

For example:
`insert all
    into table2 (id, name) values (id_seq.currval, ?)
    into table2 (id, name) values (id_seq.currval, ?)
    into table2 (id, name) values (id_seq.currval, ?)
.....
select 1 from dual;`
The select part is mandatory by the way. It works because oracle takes it as a single statement thus not incrementing the nextval sequence.